# How do firefox extensions make use of the whole screen in 3D (eg. CoolIris)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, add-in, google-chrome, cooliris

I understand that [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/) addins can be created in Javascript and Chrome.

How do they run advanced graphics applications such as [CoolIris](http://www.cooliris.com/) ?

[image]
<sub>(source: [cooliris.com](http://www.cooliris.com/static/images/product/slider1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cooliris uses native compiled code utilizing graphics acceleration on the platforms it supports.

You can get a full screen GUI if you use Flash, but the user is informed about it (try watching a YouTube vid in fullscreen) and also the user can't do everything they can otherwise, like type using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

*"Firefox addins can be created in Javascript*", It could be true
*"All Firefox Add ins are created using javascript"* might not be not true

Javascript is not the only way you can create Firefox addin, Just like Google toolbar may not have been created using javascript.Cooloris uses something more than javascript. Coolliris probably [scraps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) Content using javascript or so, and uses a custom plug in (or something like Adobe Flash ) to run advanced graphics.

I could be wrong though.

Comment: "might not be not true" ? Doesn't that mean that it might be true? ;)

Comment: it uses RSS feeds for the content

Answer (score 2):

You have to use XPCOM and write native code.